# Do .ts (Typescript) file methods cause problems with routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, angular-routing, registration

I have added multiple components in my Angular app including a registration component which allows users to register themselves; there was no issue with the frontend part until I added the methods for register.ts & userservice.ts file. After adding the methods & services, the registration page does not load when I run the app.

My question is that if any of the methods & services might be interfering with routing of the component?

These are my .ts files:

`register.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/register/userservice'; //import the user service
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; //import form modules



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.less']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  email:string ='';
  password:string ='';
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    //private router: Router,
    private UserService: UserService,
  )
 {
  this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [this.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [this.password, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    });
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.registrationForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.registrationForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    //call the user service to register the user
    this.UserService.register(this.registrationForm.controls['email'].value, this.registrationForm.controls['password'].value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      // handle the response
  });
  //error handling can b introduced
  }

}
```

`userservice.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/'; // replace with your backend URL

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //check the use of 'Observable'
  register(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/register`, data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, TypeScript file methods and services do not interfere with Angular routing. It's likely that the issue is caused by some other problem, such as incorrect configuration or code syntax errors. To troubleshoot the problem, you could check the browser console for any error messages and verify that your routing configuration is set up correctly. You can also try commenting out the methods and services in your TypeScript file and see if that fixes the issue, then gradually add them back one by one to see where the problem lies.

In my case, the error was due to not adding imports in component.spec.ts file; read the complete problem here: [Angular Registration page does not load after adding methods & services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75248496/angular-registration-page-does-not-load-after-adding-methods-services/75351332#75351332)